# How the batteryStatusChange(int status) function works in BlackBerry OS 6?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

```
public void batteryStatusChange(int status) 
{
    if(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel() == 70)
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //play a tune that tells the user that yourbattery is at 70%

    }
}
```

Looking at the documentations, status is "A combination of the BSTAT_xxx masks from DeviceInfo"

If my battery level dropped in percentage, for example, 71% to 70%, will this function will be invoked by the SystemListener2 interface even if if I don't use the status parameter?

If I wanted to be more specific in the BSTAT's, say only activate the methods inside the function when battery level has changed, rather than activating when it detects ANY type of change (like hot or cold) then this code:

```
public void batteryStatusChange(int status) 
    {
        if(status == DeviceInfo.BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED)
            if(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel() == 70)
                {
            //play a tune that tells the user that ur battery is at 70%
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                }
    }
```

is basically does the same as the first code, but with a check to the level change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `status` is a **combination** of `BSTAT_` *masks*, then I think you would want this test, to determine if the `int` value contains the `BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED` bit.

```java
public void batteryStatusChange(int status) 
{
    if ((status & DeviceInfo.BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED) != 0)
    {
        if(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel() == 70)
        {
            //play a tune that tells the user that ur battery is at 70%
        }
    }
}
```

Or, I suppose another way to track this yourself is just to record the level as a member variable:

```java
private int currentBatteryLevel = -1;

public void batteryStatusChange(int status) 
{
    int newBatteryLevel = DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel();
    if (currentBatteryLevel != newBatteryLevel) 
    {
        currentBatteryLevel = newBatteryLevel;
        if(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel() == 70)
        {
            //play a tune that tells the user that ur battery is at 70%
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but probably this code has compilation error `status & DeviceInfo.BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED`. It's not boolean value.

Comment: @EugenMartynov, thanks!  I was probably thinking in `C` when I typed that :)

Comment: Wouldn't my second code snippet work the same way as your fist code snippet? I am guessing comparing each other's bit is more accurate?

Comment: @user1615805, not necessarily.  The `status` variable can contain multiple *flags* at the same time.  You want to check that the `BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED` flag is present in `status`, but there may be other flags set (other bits set), too.  For example, I would think that `BSTAT_CHARGING` may be set at the same time.  The `&` operation just checks the bit/flag that you care about.  If you use `==`, then the test passes **only** if `BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED`, and **no other** flags are set.

Comment: Ohh, so comparing the bits would allow the tune to play even if there are more flags set other than BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED. My code with == wouldn't do that because it checks for 1 flag, and if it sees more than 1, it wouldn't execute.